# How to retain values from a textbox after page load in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have javascript and html code placed in the Content Editor Web Part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function RedirectUrl() {
 var tb = document.getElementById("tbSearch").value;
 var cs = document.getElementById("sfield").value;
 var url = "";

 if (tb != "") 
 {
    if (cs == "ID" || cs == "Column6")
    {
     url = "FilterField1=" + cs + "&FilterValue1=" + tb;
     window.location.href = "AllPages.aspx?" + url;
    }
  }
  else 
     return false;
 } 
</script>

Search Field: <select id="sfield" ClientIDMode="Static">
<option value="ID">ID</option>
<option value="Status">Status</option>
</select>

Search text: <input type="text" id="tbSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return RedirectUrl();" />
```

After the javascript executes and the page loads, the value that I have entered on the textbox and also in the drop-down list changes back to its default values. I'd like to retain those values based on the data I have entered after the page loads in SharePoint. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add some script that pulls the values from the query string and uses them to reset the input values. In SharePoint, there's an existing JS function that's part of the core.js that you can use to grab your query string parameter values. On page ready, you can then do something like this:

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var sfield = JSRequest.QueryString["cs"];
var tbSearch = JSRequest.QueryString["tb"];

document.getElementById('sfield').value = sfield;
document.getElementById('tbSearch').value = tbSearch;
```

Hope this helps!

JSRequest reference: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20820.sharepoint-2010-about-jsrequest.aspx

Comment: Hi Steve, where should i placed this code? Should i placed it in a Content Editor Web Part? I dont think i could access the On Page Ready for sharepoint using web parts...